# In C, how do I compile only one function (that requires functions from a custom library) using a makefile like so "make functionName"?

Tags: c, unit-testing, makefile, compilation, static-libraries

I'm creating a library of functions and I'd like to test one at a time using a Makefile. I write a main inside a function to test it individually. I want to run `make hello` for a file named *hello.c* and I want the output to be named *hello* which I can run using `./hello`.

Makefile:

```
NAME = libnt.a

CC = gcc -Wall -Werror -Wextra

SRC = fputchar.c fputstr.c hello.c

OBJ = $(SRC:%.c=%.o)

HDR = libnt.h

${NAME}:
    ${CC} -c -L${HDR} ${SRC}
    ar rcs ${NAME} ${OBJ}
    ranlib ${NAME}

${1}: ${1}.c ${NAME}
    ${CC} ${1}.c ${NAME} -o ${1}
```

libnt.h:

```
#ifndef HELLO_H
#define HELLO_H
#include <unistd.h>

void fputchar(int c);
void fputstr(char s[]);
void hello(void);

#endif
```

hello.c:

```
#include "libnt.h"

void hello(void)
{
    fputstr("Hello");
}

int main(void)
{
    hello();
    return (0);
}
```

As you can see, the *hello* function requires the *fputstr* function and the *fputstr* function requires the *fputchar* function but when I run `make hello`:

```
$ make hello
gcc     hello.c   -o hello
/tmp/ccczcfiM.o: In function `hello':
hello.c:(.text+0xc): undefined reference to `fputstr'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
<builtin>: recipe for target 'hello' failed
make: *** [hello] error 1
```

I suspect the libnt.a is not being compiled but I put it as one of the `${1}` rule dependencies as you can see in the Makefile, so it should compile first and then move on to the `${1}` rule action. Note the spaces in the line after `$ make hello` which, I think, means ${NAME} did not get expanded. Running `make` works perfectly.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. That `${1}` construction is new to me; are you sure it's valid Make syntax? If not, I can suggest a rule that will work.

Comment: @Beta It's a bash construct for the first argument. It works for getting the word hello as a rule if I say `make hello` but I'd like your suggestion please.

Comment: A makefile is *not* a shell script.  You can't use `${1}` like that.  Look at the correct syntax for [pattern rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Intro).

Comment: I was going to suggest a pattern rule; @G.M. has already provided a link.

Comment: @G.M. My previous rule was ${@} but it took multiple words delimited by space which is not exactly what I wanted. I'm always running the make in bash so the ${1} works perfectly fine, thank you for the link though. Looks like I'll have to read everything to figure this one out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are four major problems with your `Makefile`, assuming it is meant to be used by GNU Make.

1. You are not building the library correctly -- it must depend on the object files, and be constructed from the object files not the sources (and if you do that right then built-in rules will handle building the object files).
2. Your rule for building test programs is not correct -- you appear to be trying to use function parameter variables instead of a proper pattern rule.
3. Your object files do not depend on your header file
4. The source(s) for test(s), e.g. `hello.c`, should not be listed in `SRCS`

There area some minor nits too, including that you are making it too easy to confuse yourself between make and shell variables with `${}`.

Something like the following should work better for you (again, assuming you use GNU Make):

```
LIB = nt

override CFLAGS += -W -Wall -Werror -Wextra

SRCS = fputchar.c fputstr.c
OBJS = $(SRCS:%.c=%.o)

HDR = libnt.h

lib$(LIB).a: $(OBJS)
    $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $@ $^
    ranlib $(@)

$(OBJS): $(HDR)

override LDFLAGS += -L.

# a pattern rule to make test programs for the library
%: %.c lib$(LIB).a
    $(LINK.c) $@.c -o $@ -l$(LIB)
```

EDIT:

Sorry, I broke my own rule about not testing exactly what I posted (copy&paste is not always trivial with radically separate work and browser environments).

There were at least three problems with my first attempt:

1. I accidentally reset the default target by putting the dependency for the header file above the target for the library.
2. GNU Make does not define `$(RANLIB)`
3. I had accidentally changed the pattern rule to depend on the matching `.o` file instead of `.c`.

I also changed the *`FLAGS` settings to use an `override` directive with `+=` to allow for keeping any system defaults or command-line specified values and have the Makefile only add additional flags.

There was an additional problem in your original too that my first attempt did not fix:  The source for a test (e.g. `hello.c`) should not be included in the `SRCS` list since you do not want its/their object(s) to be included in the library.  If you want to list those sources for some other reason then do so in a separate variable.

To answer the question in your comment:  Dependencies are built in recursive order with the rules for each dependency being run before each target depending on them, so in this example all the `OBJS` are built first (using built-in rules) because the library depends upon them, and it is then built because either it is the default target, or because you specified a program target on the command file and that depends on the library (and its own source file).

Comment: Thanks @Greg. I've copied your answer over to my Makefile but it says "No rule to make target hello". Should I change the %: rule for a $(@): rule instead? Another question, does rule first check it's dependencies and then go to the action of the dependency's rule, complete that first in order to come back to complete the action of the current rule?

Comment: should be fixed now!

Comment: Odd that you omit any mention of the key error in the original makefile that is responsible for the actual error message presented there: the failure of the individual-program recipe to include libnt in the link.  You do *correct* that error, of course, but you seem to have buried the lead.  Good answer nevertheless.

Comment: On the contrary, the original attempt at writing the pattern rule _did_ mention the library both as a dependency and as a part of the link command.  It just wasn't using proper _pattern rule_ syntax so it didn't work and instead some built-in rule attempted to build the program without the library.

Comment: Still does not work but it's okay. I've decided to manually compile with `gcc hello.c libnt.a -o hello`. I'm checking out some CS50 material on Youtube 'cause the solution might be there. Thanks for the help.

Comment: When you copied my example did you remember to replace the spaces from the cut&paste with tabs on the rule command lines?